# Multiple custom fonts for multiple textview

Tags: android, textview, custom-font

One of my app activity include many textview i want to set multiple custom font for that textviews,

I tried the below code but it doesn't work to customize textview ,

any help will be appreciated

```
public class Text extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
        tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text_2)));

        TextView tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text3);
        tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text_3)));

        TextView tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text4);
        tv4.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text_4)));

        TextView tv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text5);
        tv5.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text_5)));
    }


    class MyTextView extends TextView {
        private String TextView;

        public MyTextView(Context context,int  string) {
            super(context );
        }

        public  MyTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int string) {
            if (TextView == "tv2,tv4") {
                super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                    "BFantezy.ttf"));
            }
            else if (TextView == "tv3,tv5") {
                super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                    "RoseNewB.ttf"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text2"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
          android:textSize="25sp"/>

      <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"/>


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text3"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="25sp"/>

      <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"/>

       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text4"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
          android:textSize="25sp"/>

      <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text5"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
          android:textSize="25sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: if (TextView == "tv2,tv4")...what is this!!

Comment: where do you use MyTextView  you have just defined that class.

Comment: I think naming a `String` `TextView` is one of the worst naming atrocities I've seen in a long time.

Comment: Also, you can't use == for string comparison. You need to use *fooString.equals("tv2,tv4")*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing it in a wrong way.. Do this instead

```
if (getId() == R.id.text2)                                    
           super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                 "BFantezy.ttf"));
```

and create your textView using MyTextView.

And like this compare all.

Comment: my dear please how can i include typeface and create textview in one method

Comment: in you settypface method of custom textview use the comparision i wrote in answer.. And create textview using custom textview not the normal textview

Comment: which mean:  TextView tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text4);
tv4.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text_4)));
        super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                 "BFantezy.ttf"));

Comment: whats happen to me i have 40 textviw when i did it in normal way and set string and typeface for each one its work but in mobile its too heavy and take time to open that activity any advice my friend .thanks

Comment: in your sample code in question .. you were in right track. use a custom textview. In the customTextvie' constructor set the typeface

Comment: You are creating the same typeface every time you set it. super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                 "BFantezy.ttf")); Just create it once and reuse it over and over. Typeface bf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                 "BFantezy.ttf"); This call is heavy and doing it 40 times will surely increase the load time.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the same typeface every time you set it.

```
super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "BFantezy.ttf"));
```

Just create it once and reuse it over and over. 
This call is heavy and doing it 40 times will surely increase the load time.

```
public class Text extends Activity {    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Static Typeface bf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
             "BFantezy.ttf");
    private Static Typeface rn = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), 
             "RoseNewB.ttf")

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
        tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text_2)));
        tv2.setTypeface(bf);

        TextView tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text3);
        tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text_3)));
        tv3.setTypeface(rn);

        TextView tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text4);
        tv4.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text_4)));
        tv4.setTypeface(bf);

        TextView tv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text5);
        tv5.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text_5)));}
        tv5.setTypeface(rn);
    ...
```

Custom TextView is a overkill for this purpose. You can remove the code below.

```
class MyTextView extends TextView {     
    private String TextView;
    private Static Typeface bf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
             "BFantezy.ttf");
    private Static Typeface rn = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), 
             "RoseNewB.ttf")

    public MyTextView(Context context,int string) {
        super(context);
        updateTypeface();
    } 

    public  MyTextView(Context context) {       
        super(context);      
        updateTypeface();
    }

    private void updateTypeface() {
        if (getId() == R.id.text2 || getId() == R.id.text4) {                                         
            super.setTypeface(bf);     
        } 
        else if (getId() == R.id.text3 || getId() == R.id.text5) { 
            super.setTypeface(rn);   
        }  
    }

}
```

EDIT: Updated code. Updating typeface automatically.

Comment: the same not changing font

Comment: Can you show me your layout file? Are you making the TextView custom?

Comment: also it will take id of textview not string as this:(getId() == R.id.text2

Comment: Updated the code. You don't need custom for this purpose. Its a overkill. Let me know if this works.

Comment: as i put your code : private Static Typeface bf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
             "BFantezy.ttf");
it gave error but when change to :private  final Typeface bf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                 "BFantezy.ttf"); no error , does it affect coz updeted code gave force close pointed to thst line

Comment: I didn't run the code but the change seems fine. In fact final is the right thing to do. Does it work?

Comment: NO IT DOESNT CHANGE FONT ALSO